# Java VM argument to set the windows position

Tags: java, jvm

is it possible to **start a java application with an argument that sets the window position and target screen index**?

I run my java project using *IntelliJ* and want it to start on the secondary screen. Currently I always have to drag it on my own every time I run the application. This is annoying because the window size is higher than the first screen size.

Thank you.

Comment: It does not matter how you run your project - with IntelliJ or other tools. If you're displaying JFrame, its coordinates can be changed with setLocation method

Comment: Thanks but.. I do not use JFrame and I also want to set the screen index not only the window location. The positioning will not be a feature of the app it's just for development. If it's possible I would like to avoid adding Java code to my application to achieve that..

Comment: what do you mean by not using JFrame? your app runs AWT frame/console ?

Comment: I am using OpenGL via LWJGL. Not perfectly sure what LWJGL uses but I thought it is not a JFrame. Anyway... like I have wrote, I do not need a programmatic solution. Is there a way to set the position by a VM argument or OS setting?

Comment: there is no JVM/OS setting that tell where to run java app (who needs that?) - by default they run on primary graphic device; if other behavior is needed it should be programmed explicitly

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with java and everything to do with the operating system in question

Comment: There seems to be no solution. I close this..